# ReadFile returning INVALID_HANDLE on second call

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to read data all of the data in a PCAPNG file in chunks only using the Windows API's.

I have the first read of the file working with ReadFile and the data that is being returned is correct but on our subsequent call, we are failing the ReadFile with INVALID_HANDLE.

```
    HANDLE hFile;
    DWORD dwBytesToRead = 32;
    DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
    DWORD ReadBuffer[2] = {0};

    hFile = CreateFile(LogPath.c_str(), 
            GENERIC_READ,
            0,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            NULL);
    if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return false;

    while(ReadFile(hFile, ReadBuffer, dwBytesToRead, &dwBytesRead, NULL) && dwBytesRead > 0)
    {
         std::cout << "Data from ReadBuffer[0]: " << ReadBuffer[0] << std::endl;
         std::cout << "Data from ReadBuffer[1]: " << ReadBuffer[1] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Failed with: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(hFile);
```

During the first iteration of the ReadFile, we are able to successfully read the content of the file but on the second iteration of the loop we run into an error of INVALID_HANDLE.

Basing this ReadFile loop on this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/appending-one-file-to-another-file

I am not sure what our failure reason is.

I've done some testing with SetFilePointer and the OVERLAPPED structure but I haven't had much success with either.

Am I misunderstanding the ReadFile API or is this not the right way to do what I am looking for?

Comment: Can you try GetLastError and see why is it an invalid handle?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading 32 bytes into a buffer that is only 8 bytes long.

You need to either change `ReadBuffer` to be larger, change the type from a `DWORD` to something that is 16 bytes long, or change `dwBytesToRead` to be the appropriate size (`sizeof(ReadBuffer)`, and change the declaration order).

Comment: That was absolutely correct, I was misunderstanding the ReadFile API. After adjusting the dwBytesToRead to match the size of the ReadBuffer we are iterating correctly. Thank you!